# Namespaces and spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, namespaces

I have found several SO questions similar to mine, but am struggling to find an answer that helps me, plus I'd really like to know the best practice for autoloading classes that exist within namespaces.

My folder structure:

```
root
-- classes
--- Users
---- Users.class.php
```

And users.php;

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\ProjectName\Users;

class UserMapper
{
    // class code here
}
```

And my autoload function, which sits in the root folder;

```
/* autoload classes on instatiation */
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

And, let's say I call the user class like so;

```
<?php
    new \CompanyName\ProjectName\User();
```

Warning: include(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test_tool/classes/CompanyName\ProjectName\User.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...etc

To use spl_autoload_register, do I need to map my folder structure to my namespace structure? I would prefer not to do this as I like to have my classes in the same folder, with sub folders within.

Or do I add extra code to my autoload function?

I have also searched the php manual, and there is no working namespace example, which I find very strange.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/' . str_replace("\\","/",$class) . '.class.php';`

Comment: nope, same error, sorry

Comment: also note that class name and filename should be the same...well, i did it this way

Comment: yes classname and filename are the same, I was autoloading fine before adding namespaces

Comment: @CIvemy hey, did you find out the problem??

Comment: Hi @Andrew I saw that the full fully wualified name was being passed as $class in the autoload closure. I have now followed PSR-4 implementation that can be found here http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ , mapping my directories to the namespace paths

Comment: nice they redesigned the website outlook...I always feel that namespace and autoload dont really compile tgt

Comment: I'm really surprised nothing is mentioned on the namespace or spl_autoload_register pages of the PHP manual about this

Answer (score 0):

> **Disclaimer:**  I am a beginer at php, my answer may not be correct 
>   but i'm confident *examining and testing the example bellow* will help clarify the use of **Namespaces** with **spl_autoload_register** for any beginner like me.

Consider this folder structure :

> - root/ ***contains*** index.php.
> - root/model/ ***contains*** A.php & AA.php

A.php :

```js
?php 

namespace company\model;

use \company\model\A;

class A 
{
 public function speak()
 {
  echo 'hello world! ';
 }
}
```

AA.php :

```js
?php 

namespace company\model;

use \company\model\A;

require_once 'A.php';

class AA extends A 
{
 public function shout()
 {
  echo 'HELLO WOORLD!!!';
 }
}
```

index.php :

```js
<?php 
    namespace company; 

    use \company\model\A;

    function classLoader ($className)
    {
        if (file_exists($className.'.php'))
        {
            require_once $className.'.php';
        } else {
            $className = str_replace('\\', '/', $className);
            $className = str_replace('company/', '', $className);
            if (file_exists($className.'.php'))
                require_once $className.'.php';
            else
                throw new EXCEPTION('classLoader could not find '.$className.'.php .');
      }
    }
    spl_autoload_register(classLoader);

    $obj = new A; 
    //we dont need to write ($obj = new \company\model\A;) 
    //because of statement at line 4
    $obj->speak();

    echo '<br/>';

    $objA = new \company\model\AA;  
    $objA->shout();

    echo '<br/>';

    class AB extends \company\model\AA  
    {
        public function doBoth()
        {
            $this->speak();
            $this->shout();
        }
    }

    $objB = new AB;
    $objB->doBoth();
```